# How to check empty value in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

How to check if a value is empty in a stored procedure? and if it is empty the stored procedure would then return "NULL"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1
AS
Select
  MyTable.Col1,
  HisTable.Col2
From
  MyTable Left Join
  HisTable
GO
```

In the above example, I need to check if Col2 is empty, if it is then this stored procedure should return NULL. As of now I am getting empty value
Currently this is what my returned table looks like

```
Col1  Col2
Red    1
Blue
Green  0
Yello  0
```

I want value for Col2 to be NULL for Blue

Comment: What are you defining as "empty"?

Comment: Hi Adam... empty as in empty.string or just ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this one.... :) The key was NULLIF

```
Select  MyTable.Col1,
    NULLIF(HisTable.Col2, '')
From    MyTable 
    Left Join HisTable
        ON MyTable.LinkColumn = HisTable.LinkColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the relationship between the table on the `ON` clause,

```
Select  MyTable.Col1,
        HisTable.Col2
From    MyTable 
        Left Join HisTable
            ON MyTable.LinkColumn = HisTable.LinkColumn
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you J W... very helpful link